# Is an empty "Copper vessel" allowed in baggage on Indian domestic flights?

Tags: luggage, india, domestic-travel, prohibited-items

We have (four members) planned travel to Varanasi (Coimbatore - Hyderabad - Varanasi by SpiceJet) for the purpose of getting the Ganga water to a spiritual function in my home town.

We need to carry the **empty** "Copper vessels" to get the Ganga water during the travel. The details of the vessel is Length: 5", Width: 5",  Height: 6" and Weight is 500 grams. Sample copper vessel:

[image: Sample copper vessel]

On domestic flights will they allow the "Copper vessels" in the baggage?

Comment: Seems fine for checked in. Not so sure for cabin.

Comment: Besides, the bigger point I worry about is how you will get the *filled* pot of water back.

Comment: @curious_cat: The return travel booked by train.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We have called the Spice Jet customer care and they have confirmed that they can take the copper vessel pots under the category of *Kitchen Ware* in the luggage only, **not on** cabin baggage.

Comment: I'm surprised at this restriction. Did they state a reason why the pots weren't allowed in cabin luggage? It it just a matter of being too large, or is there something specific about copper pots?

Comment: Well, on the way back, they would be full of water...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: The return travel by train.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to international standards for prohibited items, air carriers can add other items they will not (officially) allow to be taken on board. So each airline may have different rules, though they are all almost identical and the main differences are in what they charge extra for or in the items they will refuse to pay compensation for in case of damage.

A copper pot is not excluded by international standards, that cover firearms, other weapons or items that could be used as a weapon, inflammable materials and such like and no airline is in the least likely to object, whether as hold luggage or, given the small size, as cabin baggage.

You seem aware that liquids in any substantial quantity are unlikely to be allowed on board so I am guessing you have made or will make separate (non air) arrangements for any return trip with filled containers.

Comment: Restrictions on liquids are not on the liquids themselves but their containers. An empty container able to hold more than 100 ml is not allowed in carry-on luggage (though this is in reality very difficult to enforce).